# Using QuotedString in pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm having conceptual difficulty in understanding how to build a `pyparsing` parser.  The steps are: 1) build a parser by combining subclasses of ParserElement, and 2) use the parser to parse a string.

The following example works fine:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Literal, alphas, alphanums, delimitedList, QuotedString

name = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_")
field = name
fieldlist = delimitedList(field)
doc = Literal('<Begin>') + fieldlist + Literal('**End**')

dstring = '<Begin>abc,de34,f_o_o**End**'
print(doc.parseString(dstring))
```

yielding the expected sequence of tokens:

```
['<Begin>', 'abc', 'de34', 'f_o_o', '**End**']
```

But (for example), the class QuotedString does not take a ParserElement as an argument so it can't be used to build up a parser.  I'd expect to use it in the above example like:

```
name = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_")
field = QuotedString(name)     ### Wrong: doesn't allow "name" as an argument
fieldlist = delimitedList(field)
```

to parse a document of the form:

```
dstring = '<Begin>"abc", "de34", "f_o_o"**End**'
```

But since it can't be used that way, what is the proper syntax for including QuotedString in the construction of a parser for a list of quoted strings?

======== Edit ============

See answer below ...

Comment: I think you are trying to do something with `QuotedString` it is not meant for. It's for arbitrary quoted strings, not for some given subgrammar (`name` in your case) enclosed in quotes.

Comment: If you have many different identifiers that you want to parse in quotes, you could create this little helper function for yourself: `enquoted = lambda expr : Combine(Literal('"') + expr + Literal('"'))`.  `enquoted` can be called with pyparsing expressions or with strings, and the addition expression will promote strings to Literals if necessary.  Examples: `enquoted("foo")` (parses the exact word 'foo' in quotes); `enquoted(Word('A',alphas))` (parses any word starting with capital 'A', in quotes); `enquoted(Word(nums))` (parses any integer in quotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QuotedString cannot be used for this task.  But an OR function can achieve the same effect - allowing different forms of quotes while preserving the ability to parse the validity of the string contained within the quotes.  The following code does that:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Literal, alphas, alphanums, delimitedList
from pyparsing import Group, QuotedString, ParseException, Suppress

name = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_")
field = Suppress('"') + name + Suppress('"') ^ \    # double quote
        Suppress("'") + name + Suppress("'") ^ \    # single quote
        Suppress("<") + name + Suppress(">") ^ \    # html tag
        Suppress("{{")+ name + Suppress("}}")       # django template variable
fieldlist = Group(delimitedList(field))
doc = Literal('<Begin>') + fieldlist + Literal('**End**')

dstring = [
    '<Begin>"abc","de34","f_o_o"**End**',      # Good
    '<Begin><abc>,{{de34}},\'f_o_o\'**End**',  # Good
    '<Begin>"abc",\'de34","f_o_o\'**End**',    # Bad - mismatched quotes
    '<Begin>"abc","de34","f_o#o"**End**',      # Bad - invalid identifier
]

for ds in dstring:
    print(ds)
    try:
        print('  ', doc.parseString(ds))
    except ParseException as err:
        print(" "*(err.column-1) + "^")
        print(err)
```

This produces the desired output, accepting the two good test strings and rejecting the two bad ones:

```
<Begin>"abc","de34","f_o_o"**End**
   ['<Begin>', ['abc', 'de34', 'f_o_o'], '**End**']
<Begin><abc>,{{de34}},'f_o_o'**End**
   ['<Begin>', ['abc', 'de34', 'f_o_o'], '**End**']
<Begin>"abc",'de34","f_o_o'**End**
            ^
Expected "**End**" (at char 12), (line:1, col:13)
<Begin>"abc","de34","f_o#o"**End**
                   ^
Expected "**End**" (at char 19), (line:1, col:20)
```

Thank you Paul for all the help and for producing such a cool package.

Comment: Glad to see you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have some slight confusion over how to use QuotedString. The argument passed to QuotedString is *not* the string that is expected inside quotes - it is the character that is to be used as the quoting character. In this way you could define quoted strings that use '*' as quotes, or '=' as quotes, or '<' and '>' opening and closing quote chars.  In your example, just use this definition for field:

```
field = QuotedString('"')
```

Also, don't be afraid to use python's built-in help() method to access docstrings of classes, modules, methods, etc.

EDIT:

`QuotedString('X')` does *not* parse `"X"`, it parses `X some characters inside matching characters X`.

Here is your full (working) sample program:

```
from pyparsing import QuotedString, delimitedList, Group

dstring = '<Begin>"abc", "de34", "f_o_o"**End**'
field = QuotedString('"')
parser = "<Begin>" + Group(delimitedList(field)) + "**End**"

print(parser.parseString(dstring))
```

Which for me prints:

```
['<Begin>', ['abc', 'de34', 'f_o_o'], '**End**']
```

If you get an exception after copy/pasting this sample and running it, *please* post the full exception.

Some more examples:

```
starQuoteString = QuotedString('*')
eqQuoteString = QuotedString('=')
tildeQuoteString = QuotedString('~')
angleQuoteString = QuotedString('<', endQuoteChar='>')

fullSample = starQuoteString + eqQuoteString + tildeQuoteString + angleQuoteString

print fullSample.parseString("""
    *a string quoted with stars*
    =a very long quoted string, contained within equal signs=
    ~not a very long string at all~<another quoted string on the same line>
    """)
```

prints:

```
['a string quoted with stars', 'a very long quoted string, contained within equal signs', 'not a very long string at all', 'another quoted string on the same line']
```

You aren't even limited to single characters. You could use `QuotedString('**')` to parse your closing `**End**`, but then this would also accept `**The End**`, or `**Finis**`, or `**That's all folks!**`.

Comment: As shown in the edited question, that didn't work.   Any other suggestions?

Comment: I believe that the full example will not raise an exception and will try it out to verify.  But I still want to construct a parser for a list of identifiers (name) in quotes that will reject a non-identifier (e.g., "ab?c") in quotes.   My end goal is not to use QuoteString properly, it is to create a parser for a list of quoted legal strings.  Perhaps QuoteString was a red herring.

Comment: Yes, QuotedString is for parsing pretty much anything enclosed in quotes. If you have an identifier definition like `identifier = Word(alphas+'_', alphanums+'_')`, then parse for `quoted_identifier = Combine('"' + identifier + '"')`.  The Combine is there to ensure that the quotes and the identifier are all contiguous, no embedded spaces.